# JQuery Cookie Plugin not working - jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, cookies

I realize that there are a myriad of questions like this: bear with me. I'm not as good with JQuery as I am with HTML/CSS and I'm using cookies for the first time. I've got this [website](http://gersande.com/archives) that has a green banner that is supposed to go away when the user clicks the 'X'.

This is the broken JQuery that's driving me nuts:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if (!$.cookie('thecookie') || $.cookie('thecookie')==null || $.cookie('thecookie')=="") { 
        $("#headershadow").hide();
        $("#bigx").click(function(){
            $("#greenbanner").hide(1000);
            $("#headershadow").show();
            $.cookie('thecookie', 'true', { expires: 1, path: '/' });
        });
    } else {
        $("#headershadow").show();
        $("#greenbanner").hide();
    }
});
```

Essentially, I want to know why this is breaking. I need the `#greenbanner` to show up the first time you load the website, and then if you click on the `bigx` the `#greenbanner` goes away for the day. [I'm using this nifty plugin for the JQuery cookies](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

Any help to get this to stop breaking and work would be fantastic. I've been fussing with this for far too long and I'm annoyed now.

Comment: Do you want it to show up the first time every day, or the first time at all?

Comment: Setting the expiration for the cookie to 1 day was somewhat arbitrary. I wanted the average user who visits the website to not have to deal with the banner once they dismissed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your source, you are including jQuery **AFTER** the cookie plugin (*which relies on jQuery*)..

```
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Switch the order of these two, and it should help resolve your issues..

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

Also.. You seem to have a bunch or errors in your `Console`, fix these first and everything should work as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately despite applying the fixes I still don't have the code working.

Comment: It seems to work for me? the greenbox disappears on click of the `x`, the rest is just a cookie issue, you will have to store a cookie on click of the `x`, then each time the page loads, check to see when that cookie was set, and if set more than a day ago, show the `greenbox` otherwise hide it.

Comment: also, use your console to debug errors, in chrome, right click on your page > inspect element > click `Console`, This will show all the javascript errors on your page (and where they are), then its just a matter of debugging, have a go and if your still having issues, post the detailed errors/issues your having and im sure someone can help.

Comment: I have Safari in Dev mode - I do actually have access to a console in it - thanks very much for your help!